# Monitoring array for changes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to monitor a product on my own site for changes. I have stored all available sizes of the product in an array and I want to console.log once a new size gets added to the array.

I'm doing that just for practice hence why I don't want to monitor data source.

```js
for (let product of products) {
    main(product)
};

function main(product) {
    request({
        url: product.url
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(body);
            const availableSizes = []; //this stores all available sizes
            $('.size_box').each((i, el) => {
                let size = $(el).text()
                availableSizes.push(size) //adds each size to availableSizes
            })
        } else {
            console.log('Error ' + err)
            console.log('Retrying in ' + (config.delay/1000) + ' second/s')
            setTimeout(() => {
                main(product)
            }, config.delay)
        };
    });
};
```

Basically what I want to achieve/add to the code would be this:

```js
if (<no sizes added>) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        main(product)
    }, config.delay)
} else {
    console.log('New size added ' + size)
}
```

But like I said, I'm not sure how to check for specific changes to the array without just spamming all available sizes all the time.

If there's a better way of monitoring sizes for changes, feel free to suggest it, just storing all sizes in an array was the first thing that came into my mind.

Comment: You can try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-events

Comment: Still back to same issue I was pointing out in previous question. You have to store reference to the array in order to compare to the new one created each time you call `main()`. Every time you call `main()` the previous array is gone

Comment: @charlietfl i know, but i don't know how to store the previous array without changing it once main() is called

Comment: Create an object or Map outside `main()` that has product identifier as keys and sizes arrays, then compare the previous to current

Answer (score 1):

His is a bit of a hack, but unfortunately I do not know of a better way to do this. You can amend to the push function being called by over riding the push function on definition. See below:

```js
var myArr = [];

myArr.push = (...args)=>{
  logOnPush(args);
  Array.prototype.push.apply(myArr, args);
}

function logOnPush(res){  
  var container = document.getElementById("displayContainer");
  container.innerText = container.innerText+'\n'+'Items added: ' + res;
  console.log('Items added: ', res);
}

function addToArray(){
  myArr.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 10));
  var container = document.getElementById("displayContainer");
  container.innerText = myArr.join(', ');
}

document.getElementById("addBtn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  addToArray();
});
```

```html
<button id="addBtn">Add to array</button>
<p id="displayContainer"></p>
<p id="consoleContainer"></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could create a custom class, with its data being updated with a custom `push` method. This class would act exactly as an Array object (you could even extend the Array class), but you can then add your custom behavior

Take a look at this page for an example: https://github.com/wesbos/es6-articles/blob/master/54%20-%20Extending%20Arrays%20with%20Classes%20for%20Custom%20Collections.md